# Powershell I don't get the log to work

Tags: powershell

I have recently started with Powershell and I have been trying to use it as much as I can, but I get quite frustrated.
I have this code which does what I want, but the log doesn't work but I don't get errors:

```
Function logWrite
{
param ([string]$logstring)
$Computer = gc env:computername
$date = $(Get-Date -UFormat "%d-%m-%Y")
$Logfile = C:\Windows\Temp\Key-KB-Testing-$Computer-$date.log
Add-content -Path $Logfile -Value $logstring
}

$Stamp = (Get-Date).toString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") 
logWrite "Testing KB3142037"
$KB3142037result= gwmi -cl win32_reliabilityRecords -filter "sourcename = 'Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient'" | where { $_.message -match 'KB3142037'} | select -Expand Message  
logWrite $Stamp
logWrite "Testing KB3142033"
$KB3142033result= gwmi -cl win32_reliabilityRecords -filter "sourcename = 'Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient'" | where { $_.message -match 'KB3142033'} | select -Expand Message
logWrite $Stamp
$Key = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319\ -Name SchUseStrongCrypto | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SchUseStrongCrypto
$arquitecture = (gwmi win32_computersystem).SystemType

If ($arquitecture -eq "x32-based PC")
{   
   If ($Key -eq $true)
    {
        logWrite "The key exist and the value is '$Key'"
        if ($Key -ne "0")
        {
            Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '0' -Type DWord -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose
            logWrite "The key has been modified"
            logWrite $Stamp
        }
    } 
Else { 
        logWrite "There is no key. New registry key will be created"
        New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319 -Name SchUseStrongCrypto -PropertyType DWord -Value 0 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose
        logWrite $Stamp
        logWrite "The Key has been created"
    }

}
Else
{
    If ($Key -eq $true)
    {
        logWrite "The key exist and the value is '$Key'"
        if ($Key -ne "0")
        {
            Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '0' -Type DWord -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose
            logWrite "The key has been modified"
            logWrite $Stamp
        }
    } 
Else { 
        logWrite "There is no key. New registry key will be created"
        New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319 -Name SchUseStrongCrypto -PropertyType DWord -Value 0 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose
        logWrite $Stamp
        logWrite "The Key has been created"
    }

}
```

Any help, links or guidance will be helpfull.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Regards

Comment: Where do you specify $Logfile

Comment: Writing into a system directory might cause problems with UAC and stuff. Change the path to, say, `C:\temp` and grant write permissions to appropriate user accounts/groups.

Comment: What do you mean by "the log doesn't work"? Is the logfile not created at all? Is it empty? Is the content wrong?

Comment: The logfile doesn't create, so, the content isn't added. I have to modify those keys, so, that part is cover, but, my idea was to generate a log with the different things that the script does. I have tried different paths within the function.     Function logWrite
{
param ([string]$logstring)
$Computer = gc env:computername
$date = $(Get-Date -UFormat "%d-%m-%Y")
$Logfile = C:\Windows\Temp\Key-KB-Testing-$Computer-$date.log
Add-content -Path $Logfile -Value $logstring
}

Comment: Why is the path to the logfile not quoted? The way you write it, it would try to do the default windows action for the the given file (or throw an error if it doesn't exist) and assign the return to the variable.

Comment: And btw, you can write `$Computer = $env:computername`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$Logfile = "C:\Windows\Temp\Key-KB-Testing-$Computer-$date.log"
```

Comment: Thanks and I feel so embarrassed... now works " "... sorry for this question, but, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @DiegoVictorino please mark this as the correct answer if this worked for you.

Comment: I still don't understand why you didn't get any error though.

Comment: If you copy/paste the script, once you execute it, it doesn't give you an error. That's why I felt frustrated, because normally I look for code, help or information and usually I get the answer, but, this time without an error, I didn't know how to solve it.

Comment: If I execute just the function declaration with a single call like `Logwrite "Hello"`, I *do* get an error, because the log file name doesn't exist.